# Deleting Dropbox files from PC, phone, and web

Tags: dropbox

I have 2 Windows computers and 1 Android phone all signed up with my Dropbox account.  I want to delete some old photos from my Dropbox account (I already have them manually copied to a different archive folder on my PC that isn't linked with Dropbox. )  When I delete them from the Dropbox folder with one computer, they aren't getting out of Dropbox folder on the other computer or the phone.  I wind up with files that have names saying there was 'contention'.

Do I have to delete them from the web-interface to Dropbox?

Comment: That is odd. In my experience, Dropbox is rather good at managing that sort of thing. How are you deleting them? Just select, then `File > Delete`? Are you deleting a large number of files? Certainly deleting them from the web is an option. I'd experiment a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you delete a file from a Dropbox folder, it's synched over all devices under this account.. Been using Dropbox for something like 2 years on different devices both at work and at home and there have never been such a thing. Make sure that all the files are in the Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

If these photos are from your camera roll, there's an obvious problem.

If the photos are still on your android devices in your camera roll, they'll be resynced.

The solution that's worked for me is to delete them from your camera roll, and then use the Dropbox website to delete, not the client application. From what I've learned, the website has the final say as far as what's in your Dropbox.